# How to make the view static until other view controller appear?

Tags: ios, ios7

Situation:
From the First Image there have view 1 which is it will have animation from left to right when run the app. After that, user will click "Proceed" button and continue to View Controller 2 but before it show the view controller 2, the view 1 will disappear as what you can see in Second Image. How to make the view1 static over there until view controller 2 appear?

[image][image]

Comment: Maybe you should use the term "be in the same place" not "static" as it could misguide somebody that this is related to "static elements of the class".

Comment: Once a view is visible, you have to take action to make it disappear. (Like set its alpha=0, remove it from superview, change its frame, etc).  Does your code do any of that?

Comment: Do you mean, that View1 is disappearing when you "push" new ViewController ?

Comment: Look at the lifecycle callbacks that are called when your first "ViewController" is covered by new "ViewController" that is :
viewWillDisappear:, viewDidDisappear. Maybe as suggested by @danh you've made some action to remove or move your view.

Comment: @bluesm ya the view1 disappearing when i push to new view controller.

Comment: @danh i didn't set it to alpha or removed from superview

Comment: @danh Show use the code code you think could help us help you :)

Comment: Why don't you fade View1 out using animateWithDuration:animations:completion:, and call performSegue in the completion block.

Comment: @rdelmar because at the view1 actually i need to let user enter username n password after tat press the "Proceed" button only present view controller2

Comment: I don't understand that comment. You can have the user enter their user name and password, then when they press proceed, you have View1 disappear, and call the segue from the completion block. If that's not what you want, you need to explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: @user4302196 Maybe you can record the video simulator showing the problem ?